# client server applet java (bouncing ball)

Tags: java, сервер, applet

Здравствуйте, суть состоит в следующем: есть сервер, к нему коннектится апплет и запускает у себя шарик. Апплет является клиентом. Каждый пользователь при подключении к серверу видит свой шарик. Коннектится к серверу нормально, а при передаче данных со строки `out.writeInt(x);` происходит падение

> java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket
>   write error
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
>           at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
>           at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(Unknown Source)
>           at Server.run(Server.java:51)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Кто подскажет, где ошибка?

Код сервера:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server implements Runnable {
   Socket csocket;
   int x,y,dx,dy,diam,sizex,sizey;
   double k;
   DataInputStream in;
   DataOutputStream out;
   Server(Socket csocket) {
      this.csocket = csocket;
      this.x=this.y=0;
      this.dx=this.dy=5;
      this.sizex=800;
      this.sizey=500;
      this.diam=20;
      this.k=0.2;
      try 
      {
        in = new DataInputStream(csocket.getInputStream());
        out = new DataOutputStream(csocket.getOutputStream());
      } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
   }

   public static void main(String args[]) 
   throws Exception {
      ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(1234);
      System.out.println("Listening");
      while (true) {
         Socket sock = ssock.accept();
         System.out.println("Connected");
         new Thread(new Server(sock)).start();
      }
   }
   public void run() 
   {

    while (true)
    {
        try {
        Thread.currentThread().sleep(30);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {};
        x+=dx; y+=dy;
        diam = (int)(diam*k);
        if ((x<=0)||(x+dx+diam>=sizex)) dx=-dx;
        if ((y<=0)||(y+dy+diam>=sizey)) dy=-dy;
        //k = 1 - 1.6*(Math.sqrt((x-sizex/2)*(x-sizex/2)+(y-sizey/2)*(y-sizey/2)))/(Math.sqrt((sizex*sizex)+(sizey*sizey)));
        try 
        {
          out.writeInt(x);
          out.writeInt(y);
          out.writeInt(diam);
          out.flush();
        } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

   }
}
```

Код апплета-клиента:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.applet.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Ball extends Applet implements Runnable {
  int r,g,b,x,y,diam;
  public void init() {
    setBackground(Color.white);
    r=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("red"));
    g=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("green"));
    b=Integer.parseInt(getParameter("blue"));
    (new Thread(Ball.this)).start();
  }

  public void run() 
  {
      int serverPort = 1234;
      String address = "127.0.0.1";
      try 
      {
                InetAddress ipAddress = InetAddress.getByName(address);
            Socket socket = new Socket(ipAddress, serverPort);
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                x = in.readInt();
                y = in.readInt();
                diam = in.readInt();
                repaint();
            }
      } catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
  }

  public void paint(Graphics graph) 
  {
    graph.setColor(new Color(r,g,b));
    graph.fillArc(x,y,diam,diam,0,360);
  }
  public void UserColor(int Red, int Green, int Blue)
  {
       r=Red; g=Green; b=Blue; 
  }
}
```

Comment: А что за падение-то? Трассировка не помешала бы.

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write
error

Comment: Не удается повторить. Может быть локальное что-то (фаерволы/антивирусы)? Попробуйте на другом компьютере. Падает клиент или сервер? Падает сразу, или через какое-то время?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Падает сервер:
java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(Unknown Source)
        at Server.run(Server.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Так в чем все таки была проблема?

Comment: Надо было через сервер запускать апплет, поставил апач, все заработало

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все очень просто. Вы забыли после записи выполнить очистку буфера: `out.flush();`

```
try 
{
   out.writeInt(x);
   out.writeInt(y);
   out.writeInt(diam);
   out.flush();
} catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace();}
```

Comment: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt(Unknown Source)
        at Server.run(Server.java:51)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Решение не помогло.

Comment: Вы проверяли настройки фаервола? У меня нет эксепшенов. Код полностью рабочий.

Comment: У меня есть. Я уже отключал антивирусы. Все равно exception